# Sequelize eager loading if an array contains an ID

Tags: javascript, postgresql, axios, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize with a postgresql database, which natively supports arrays.  So I am trying to load a single artifact by pk, and all artists where the artistID is contained within the artist model at artist.artifactID, which is an array of integers.

If I don't try to eagerly load the artists and just load them all it returns the proper data.  I'm sure I'm not eagerly loading the data correctly, but I haven't had any luck finding info on this since arrays in Sequelize are specific to postgresql databases.

Sorry if the answer is obvious, I'm new and still learning.

**API**

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
const { Artist, Post, Artifact } = require('../db');


//GET /api/ all artifacts
router.get('/', async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const artifactList = await Artifact.findAll();
        res.send(artifactList)
    } catch (e) {
        next(e);
    }
});

router.get('/:id', async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const artifact = await Artifact.findByPk(req.params.id);
const artists = await Artist.findAll({
            where: {
                artifactID: {
                [Op.in]: parseInt(req.params.id)
                }
            }
        });
        res.send({artifact, artists});
    } catch (e) {
        next(e);
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

**ERROR**

```
GET https://octopus-house.herokuapp.com/api/artifacts/1 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was close, here is the correct query:

```
const artists = await Artist.findAll({
            where: {
                artifactID: {
                    [Op.contains]: [req.params.id]
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: If anyone that understands the query sees this, why do I have to write it this way?  Why is the required value inside an array?